# Database tables with unknown amount of columns

Tags: database

This is something I've been wondering about for quite a while. And since I am creating a program where I need to do it i want to ask you guys what you do when you "hit" the following case:

Lets say for instance that you have a chat program. In this program people can send messages back and forward.

Now you want to store a conversations between an unknown amount of people.

Now what you could do is have a `message` table and then for each of the `users` who are involved in the conversation you add a row.

Now if you have anything other than a small size program this message table would quickly expand to a very Large size

So I guess my question is what do you do in this case?

Comment: why are you asking about "unknown amount of columns" ?

Comment: I don't really see what the question is. You'd store the user in one column and the message in the other column.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli The question was abit hard to explain but it is about having an unknown amount of users sending alot of messages privately to eachother. how do you store that message so that you can look up the message and see all the users who "could read" that individual message meaning which user was involved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create multi recipient messages you can create a messages table which has:

- id
- sender -> users.id
- text
- time

and a message_recipients table which has:

- message -> messages.id
- recipient -> users.id
- is_read

This will still have the same (large) amount of rows, but those will be in the message_recipients table which is only a few bytes per row.